# which sentences can this grammar generate?

Tags: prolog, grammar, dcg

Here is a tiny lexicon and a minigrammar consisting of one syntactic rule, I
have to list all the sentences that this grammar can generate in the order
that Prolog will generate them in, I know that the first sentence would be: a
criminal eats a criminal, but then I don't know how to find the other
sentences, how does the Prolog interpreter works on these cases? I don't want
you to give me all the answers, I just need a little clue.

```
word(determiner,a).
word(determiner,every).
word(noun,criminal).
word(noun,'big kahuna burger').
word(verb,eats).
word(verb,likes).

sentence(Word1,Word2,Word3,Word4,Word5):-
    word(determiner,Word1),
    word(noun,Word2),
    word(verb,Word3),
    word(determiner,Word4),
    word(noun,Word5).
```

Comment: Did you try running it? Prolog will look for all solutions to `sentence` that match the database.

Answer (score 1):

Prolog has a relational data model, and uses the comma to mean AND.
There are 2 choices for each word kind, then there will be 2 solutions for each word occurrence.

The next phrase generated will use the first alternative available, and since the execution model is *depth first* search, such alternative will be the next *noun* after *criminal*.

Now, since Prolog exhausted the alternatives for the last word, it will 'go back', to see if a different *determiner* is available. It will find *every*, then it will try - again - all alternatives for *noun*, etc etc

Answer (score 1):

As always when describing lists, consider using a DCG. Your code can be written like this with DCG nonterminals:

```
determiner --> [a].
determiner --> [every].

noun --> [criminal].
noun --> ['big kahuna burger'].

verb --> [eats].
verb --> [likes].
```

A "sentence" in your case is a list that is described with the following nonterminal:

```
sentence --> determiner, noun, verb, determiner, noun.
```

Notice that `(,)//2` in DCGs can be read as "and then".

The sentences that are described with this grammar can then be enumerated with:

```
?- phrase(sentence, Ls).
Ls = [a, criminal, eats, a, criminal] ;
Ls = [a, criminal, eats, a, 'big kahuna burger'] ;
Ls = [a, criminal, eats, every, criminal] ;
etc.
```

where you press SPACE to see further solutions.